# How to call tostring method on all objects

Tags: c#, class, object, tostring

I have a school project where I have to make every tostring method appear on every object. Does anyone know how to do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHC6x.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXimm.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(Escola escola in IPP.Escolas)
{
    Console.WriteLine(escola .ToString());
}
```

You can use the [foreach](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/foreach-loop) loop to print every element on the array.

Comment: it's giving me this error in the code part (escla. ToString().   CS1503 - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'